# ExtJS--TreeStore making duplicate requests when load() is called

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a treestore, lets call it TreeB, that needs to be filtered/reloaded based on a selection from another tree. But when I call the load method, the proxy for this particular treestore makes 2 requests. This is very strange behavior that I have never experienced before. I actually have multiple treestores all configured the same way and I call the load() method on all of them at the same time, but its TreeB that makes the duplicate requests. I listen for the "itemclick" event on the first tree, change the url for the other treestores, add some extraParams and reload.

//treeA itemclick handler

```
handleFilterTrees: function(tree_, rec_){  
  this.getTreeB().getStore().getProxy().url = "blah.html";//overwriting url configured in store proxy
  this.getTreeB().getStore().getProxy().extraParams = {treeA:rec_.data.id};
  this.getTreeB().getStore().load();
}
```

thats it. I use the same exact logic to filter two more trees in the same handler and they work fine.

heres my store:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.store.Reports", {
  extend:"Ext.data.TreeStore",
  lazyFill:true,
  autoLoad:false,
  fields:["id", "text", "leaf"],
  root: {
    text:"reprts",
    id: '0',
    expanded:true
  },
  proxy: {
    timeout:"1200000",
    type: 'ajax',
    url: './abc.html',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
  },
  listeners:{
    beforeload:function(store){
      if(store.isLoading()){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

});
```

so has anyone experienced this before? Is there anyway to stop the store from making multiple requests? I tried checking isLoading() but it gets ignored.

Comment: You could try sticking a breakpoint in your beforeload handler and working back through the stack trace to see what is calling load on that store both times. Could give you some clues anyway

Comment: Place this code in your JS file add this line of code `Ext.util.Observable.capture(myObj, function(evname) {console.log(evname, arguments);})` [More here](https://coderwall.com/p/jnqupq/easily-capture-all-events-on-a-component-in-extjs)

Comment: It is a bug and as i know it is resolved in last version. Which version do you use?

Comment: thanks for your replies. It actually ended up being a backend issue. I Didnt think backend could somehow force the client to duplicate a request but i guess its possible